# How to wait for findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock (in Parse) finish then run the MainThread?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, cocoa-touch, parse-platform

I am using Parse to store my data. In my AppDelegate I want to get all my data from server then shared them to my ViewController but I cant do it. Because my MainThread always finish before my collect data thread. Is there any way to get all data first, or wait for the data thread finish then do the Mainthread, or another way to implement this.

This is my code:

```
@synthesize authors;
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [SCategory registerSubclass];
    [Parse setApplicationId:PARSE_APP_ID clientKey:PARSE_CLIENT_KEY];

     PFQuery *query = [SCategory query];

    // type =1 : programmes
   [query whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@1];
   [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {

            // The find succeeded.
            authors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
            NSLog(@"inside block author: %d",[authors count]);
       } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];



   NSLog(@"outside block author: %d",[authors count]);

        return YES;
    }
```

My Output

```
2013-11-15 15:00:59.424 Sala[5340:70b] outside block author: 0
2013-11-15 15:01:00.804 Sala[5340:70b] inside block author: 4
```

I want my "outside block author = 4" but >.<

Comment: you can use dispatch queues or NSOperationQueue

Comment: can you give more information, or example because i'm newbie? Thank you

Comment: If you want the main thread to wait, why don't you use the asynchronous methods?

Comment: How to use it? Parse only provide me method "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" to get data from server.

Comment: try this dispatch_queue_t queue= dispatch_queue_create("Parse data", 0);
    
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // to get all  data from server  and parsing
        
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // share data to other view controllers in main thread
        });
    });

Comment: @Savitha I try yours but output is still 0

Comment: I seperate to 2 comments, because it too long they dont allow to post   dispatch_queue_t queue= dispatch_queue_create("Parse data", 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
   
        [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                
                // The find succeeded.
                authors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
                NSLog(@"inside block author: %d",[authors count]);
            }

Comment: else {
                // Log details of the failure
                NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            }
        }];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           
        // share data to other view controllers in main thread
            NSLog(@"outside block author: %d",[authors count]);

        });
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what is the solution, I decided not use findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock but to use findobject only, so this method will run synchronous. `authors = [query findObjects];`

Comment: Unless you have a specific reason to use a synchronous method you should use the asynchronous one so you can easily keep the UI active.

Answer (score 1):

You should not want to or try to block the main thread. The whole point of the block is that it's an asynchronous process and you should deal with that.

The correct approach is to either:

Get the data in the app delegate and then, in the success block, get the view controller and pass it the data.

Or:

Move the logic to the view controller so that when it's shown it decides if it needs to get the data and it manages the download and then updates its UI.

Comment: can you show me an example how to pass data in success block, I dont know how to do :(

Comment: You already create `authors` from `objects`. You next need to get the instance of your view controller (you'd need to show code for how it's created) and pass the `authors` to it.